# SQL Aggregate While performing CASE on different field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data that looks like this:

```
SampleID  Result  Qualifier
A1          2      NULL
A1          1      NULL
B2          4      NULL
B2          5       >
```

I want to aggregate (sum) the result, but keep the 'most conservative' Qualifier in the set.  In this case, the '>' is more conservative than the 'NULL'

In other words, This is what I want for my output.

```
SampleID  SumResult  Qualifier
A1           3         NULL
B2           9          >
```

Is this possible? At first I thought I could use a Case statement, but reading online has indicated it is not possible to use these on multiple records.

Note there's only a handful of possible 'Qualifiers'.

`SELECT 
      [SampleID]
      ,SUM([Result]) AS [SumResult]
      --,CASE WHEN (One or more [qualifier] are '>', return '>', else return NULL) AS [Qualifier]
FROM [tblData]
GROUP BY
      [Sample ID]`

Comment: If there's only a handful of qualifiers, can you list them out and what there priorities are in the question?

Comment: perhaps add a priority column
case when qualifier '<' then 3
case when qualifier '>' then 2
case when qualifier '-' then 1
case else 0
end
now sort on priority column and take the FIRST of the qualifier field

Comment: I'd have to look carefully at the schema, but let's assume the following order (decreasing importance) '>', 'ND', '*', NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MAX`:

```
SELECT 
      [SampleID]
      ,SUM([Result]) AS [SumResult]
      CASE MAX(CASE Qualifier
      WHEN '*' THEN 1   WHEN 'ND' THEN 2   WHEN '>' THEN 3 END)
      WHEN 1 THEN '*'   WHEN 2 THEN 'ND'   WHEN 3 THEN '>' END as Qualifier
FROM [tblData]
GROUP BY
      [Sample ID]
```

Of course, if the qualifiers actually have your desired sort order as strings, you don't need to translate to/from integers using the `CASE` expressions and can directly apply `MAX` (or `MIN`).

---

For more than a handful of qualifiers, you just store this mapping to/from integers as two columns in another table and use that rather than the `CASE` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

For what you want, `max()` should do the trick:

```
SELECT [Sample ID], SUM([Result]) AS [SumResult], MAX(Qualifier) as Qualifier
FROM [tblData]
GROUP BY [Sample ID];
```